# Automatically remove explicit package declarations with import statements in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, import, package

I have a project created by others that includes thousands of class files and has the package names explicitly typed out for every reference to any of their classes. It looks like the code was reverse engineered. Is there a good tool for Java that refactors the code so that the explicitly typed package prefixes are removed from class references and moved into import statements.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

I think an example will help. I want to have the imports at the top, and I don't care how many imports there are.

```
javax.swing.JButton button1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
```

Imagine the code above but absolutely everywhere in thousands upon thousands of lines of code amongst thousands of class files. I would like to be able to remove all of the prefixes and just have a nice import javax.swing.JButton; at the top of each class file.

Comment: This is just wrong. We shouldn't steal others work, and we shouldn't assist anyone doing so.

Comment: @irreputable : this is not necessarly stealing. this can be a case where the user has the right to use a lib, but the original manufacturer or responsible is gone, and with it the source code and possible bugfixes. In these cases all you can do is reverse the thing and try to correct bugs yourself

Comment: No one is stealing anyone's work. I am working on a research project with my university that has explicit permission to use and modify another university's source code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know a tool for this use case, but I had to do something similar a few month ago.

- Write a script or do a search replace with regex to get rid of the explicitly typed package prefixes.
- Than let eclipse do the rest using "organize imports". Ctrl-1

Hint: to avoid  ambiguities, setup the classpath with no more than the required libs.
For sround about 800 classes I was done in 2 hours.

- Or get someone who deserved it to do this job.

EDIT: You should know that in Prefeneces/Java/Editor/Save Actions, Organize imports can be configured as save action.

Comment: Yes this is what I thought I would have to do. Only 2 hours once the regex is written... sounds promising and may be doing that. Thank you.

Comment: It might not be as simple as removing all explicit package references; if there are ambiguities (same class name) then those explicit references need to remain.

Comment: Using eclipse's save actions, at least the order (and visibility) can be changed

Comment: Does somebody have an example for the Regexp?

Comment: It's hard to come up with a single regular expression for all of this, but you could do something like this: highlight everything but your existing list of imports and do CTRL-F to Find/Replace. Search for "(org|com).[a-z.]*" and make sure you have "regular expressions" and "case-sensitive" options checked. Then replace with "" (nothing). Then "Organize Imports" and guess at what each of the imports should be. :)

Answer (score 5):

For a single type, eclipse offers the 'Add import' action (Shift+Ctrl+M). It does exactly what you want - with the big, big limitation: you have to place the cursor on a type and it will only affect that 'selected' occurrence.

But maybe this action can be used in a scripted/global method. A JDT plugin could crawl through the AST and call this action on every type it finds.

Comment: I will have to look into scripting that, however I don't know if it'd be easier just to write a script that finds and replaces using a regex. Still, if I could find a plugin that's already written I will certainly try using it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[This thread](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t41120.html) says:

> select the package explorer view, right click on your project, choose source then organise imports. Bobs your uncle - all unwanted imports are removed

To make it better formatted:

`Right click project > Source > Organize imports`

Now, what remains, is to find a way to strip the fully-qualified names from the code. You may think of some regular expression. Take a look at [this library](http://innig.net/macker/guide/regex.html) - it seems helpful. [This article](http://ourcraft.wordpress.com/2009/01/29/a-regex-to-selectively-remove-package-from-class-names/) should also be useful.

Comment: This will not change fully qualified type declarations (e.g. `java.awt.Font foo`) to unqualified declarations (e.g. `Font foo`) with import statements. At least, this is the case in Eclipse 3.5.

Comment: yes, I updated my answer with the next (previous, actually) step towards that goal

Comment: Interesting library and article... I will have to look into these to see how easy I can apply it to my project, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I use an [Eclipse plugin](http://blog.mi-ernst.de/projekte) by Michael Ernst that does what you want. It converts references such as `java.util.Collection` to `Collection` with the addition of an `import java.util.Collection;` at the top of the file.

It is effectively the same thing as using "Source -> Add Import" for a fully-qualified reference except that it lets you do it for an entire .java file at once.

Even better, it lets you batch-process all the .java files you have selected in the Package Explorer. Simply right-click on the selection and select "Source -> Clean qualified Type Declarations" form the contextual menu.

Eclipse update site: http://cqtp.sourceforge.net/eclipse/

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ Idea has tools to do this on a per-file basis.  You can probably also do it in bulk, but I don't know how.

Try out a 30 day evaluation and you'll probably be pleased by more than the import cleanup features.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with axis generated files, and I wrote a small groovy script to do this. I doesn't do everything (you have to use organize imports in eclipse after you run it), and I haven't tested it very well, so use it carefully. It's also limited to lowercase package names and camel-cased class names, but it may be a good starting point

```
def replaceExplicitPackageNamesInFile(File javaFile){
 eol = org.codehaus.groovy.tools.Utilities.eol()

 newFile = ""
 explicitImportExpr = /([^\w])(([a-z0-9]+\.)+)([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+)/
 imports = ""
 javaFile.eachLine { 
  line = it.replaceAll(explicitImportExpr, {
   Object [] match ->
   imports += "import ${match[2]+match[-1]};${eol}"
   match[1]+match[-1]
  })
  newFile += line+"${eol}" 
 }
 newFile2 = ""
 newFile.eachLine { line ->
  newFile2 +=
   line.replaceAll(/(^\s*package.*$)/, {
    Object [] match ->
    match[0] + eol + imports
   } ) + eol
 }
 javaFile.setText(newFile2)
}

def replaceExplicitPackageNamesInDir(File dir){
 dir.eachFileRecurse {
  if (it.isFile() && it.name ==~ /.*\.java\z/){
   println "Processing ${it.absolutePath - dir.absolutePath}"
   replaceExplicitPackageNamesInFile(it)
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to replace all `javax.swing.`. Then do organize imports.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to remove all explicit package names in interfaces by running the sed command below on target files, then by reorganize imports in eclipse:

```
sed -e 's/java\.[^ ]*\.//g;s/com\.[^ ]*\.//g'
```