# Organize import in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, wsdl, refactoring, javabeans

Making my first WSDL project from scratch, I've faced some discomfort using Eclipse.
After generating Java beans skeleton, Eclipse placed paths to Java classes in generated files:

```
package com.examples.www.wsdl.HelloService_wsdl;

public class HelloWorld_BindingImpl implements com.examples.www.wsdl.HelloService_wsdl.HelloWorld_PortType{
    public java.lang.String sayHello(java.lang.String firstName) throws java.rmi.RemoteException {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Does Eclipse have any methods to place all of this big classpath staff to imports?

Comment: I removed "static" from "static import" in your question.  In Java, a static import is importing static methods/fields.  Not what we have here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  See [some alternatives here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142537/automatically-remove-explicit-package-declarations-with-import-statements-in-jav).  Note that these are called fully qualified names, not static imports.

Answer (score 0):

A WSDL class generator typically generates Java source code over and over again especially when changes are made to `WSDL` or `XSD` files. For this reason it is better to avoid constantly refactoring the output files.

One option that is typically used is to subclass the implementation output file, `HelloWorld_BindingImpl` in this case.